# Inject different service instance into controller

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, code-injection, autowired

I have the following Controller and Service

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
   @Autowired
   private MyService myService;

  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/connect.do")
  public String connect(Model model)
  {
    invokeService();
    return  "xxx";
  }

  private void invokeService()
  {
        myService.test();
  }

}


@Service
public class MyService
{
 private int value1 = 200;
 private int value2 = 333;
 private String value3 ;
 private String value4 ;
 private String value5 ;
 ....

 public void test()
 {
        System.out.println(value1++);
        foo();
  }

 private void foo()
 {

 }
```

}

When I use 2 browsers to connect to the application, the output is "200" and "201", which means Spring inject the same MyService instance into the controller for different connection.

I need the output to be "200" and "200" when I use 2 different connections to access the application, because I need to share values1, values2, value3, etc between "test()" and "foo()". How to do it in Spring? Basically, I want Spring to inject different instance for different connection. I tried @Scope("prototype") in Service bean and it doesn't work.

I can make it work by using:

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    private void invokeService()
   {
        new MyService.test();
   }
}
```

I am just wondering that how to do it in Spring.

Another way of asking this question is: How to have multiple controller instances (one for each user connection) as opposed to one controller instance serving for all connections?

EDIT: I can see the difference of prototype (output: 200 200 200 200) and singleton (output: 200 201 202 203) by using the follow code and 2 browser connections

```
private void invokeService() 
{ 
  myService = applicationContext.getBean( MyService.class ); 
  new MyService.test();
  myService = applicationContext.getBean( MyService.class ); 
  new MyService.test(); 
}
```

But when I put "applicationContext.getBean( MyService.class )" in postConstructor instead:

```
public class MyController implements ApplicationContextAware {

private SearchService searchService;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    searchService = applicationContext.getBean( SearchService.class );
}

protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext( ApplicationContext applicationContext ) throws BeansException {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

}
```

and use "@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)" on MyService, the output are still "200" and "201" when I use 2 browsers to connection to the application

Comment: I can see the difference of prototype and singleton by using the follow code    private void invokeService()
   {    myService = applicationContext.getBean( MyService.class );
        new MyService.test(); myService = applicationContext.getBean( MyService.class );
        new MyService.test();
   }  But when I use getBean method in postConstructor instead, the output are still "200" and "201" when I use 2 browsers to connection to the application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Autowired` doesn't mix with `@Scope("prototype")` uness you enable proxy generation (which is probably not what you want - it quickly gets complex).

Make your `MyController` `ApplicationContextAware` instead:

```
public class MyController implements ApplicationContextAware {

    public MyService getMyService() {
        return applicationContext.getBean( MyService.class );
    }

    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext( ApplicationContext applicationContext ) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

Now `@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` will work as expected.

Note that you will get a new instance of `MyService` every time you call `getMyService()`.

Why doesn't your approach (and my old one) doesn't work? `MyController` is a singleton, so the field `myService` is wired exactly once - Spring can't give you a new instance of the bean every time you access the field for two reasons:

1. It would mean that Spring would have to analyze the byte code of the class to find all places where the code accesses the field.
2. It would break in other ways. For example when you call two methods of the bean:

   myService.foo();
      myService.bar(); // do you *really* want a new bean here?

PS: If you use Spring < 3.1.2, you will want to specify the ID of the bean since `getBean(Class<?> type)` was very slow for those versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I copy the controller code you provided without using "@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)" in Service, and it works as my expectation.   But could you please explain it a little bit why this gives me 2 different Service instances?

Comment: Sorry, it was my misoperation. I follow your instruction I still get "200" and "201" in the output

Comment: Ah, damn :-) Fell into the same trap as you. I've edited my answer; it should work now. Please try again.

Comment: basically we need to call applicationContext.getBean( MyService.class) every time before I use MyService to get a brand new instance (and it is actually the same as new Myservice().test()). But the design of Spring doesn't make sense to me. For example, in my opinion, "myService.foo(); myService.bar()" should use the same myService instance if these 2 calls are invoked in one client HTTP request; if these 2 calls are invoked by 2 client HTTP requests, then there should be 2 different MyService instances

Comment: MyController shouldn't be a singleton, or at least Spring should provide user the ability to set it to non-singleton.

Comment: In that case, use the `request` scope for controller and service.

Comment: I made it work by using @Scope( "prototype" ) on both MyController and MyService, and "@Autowired MyService myService". Thanks a lot for your time and discussion!